# Why can't I use the ScaffoldState Class in Material3 with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

**I want to add ScaffoldState to my AppBar**

```
@Composable
  fun HomeAppBar(scaffoldState : ScaffoldState, scope : CoroutineScope)
  { 
  //content 
  }
```

Comment: What is the error here? Kindly provide a minimal reproducible example.